# std::unordered_map containing another std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, hashtable, unordered-map

We are working on a game project for school in c++.
I'm in charge of the map object, who will contain Entities like bombs, players, walls and boxes.
I have 3 containers in my map:

- A std::list for players (multiple players can stand on a same case).
- A `std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, AEntity*> >` for walls.
- An other `std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, AEntity*> >` for bombs+boxes.

The aim is to access an Entity very fast on the map, number of entities can be very high.

That's why I thought about unordered_maps, I planned to use them this way:

```
Unordered_map A contain:
  KEY: y coord of the Entity || VALUE: pointer to unordered_map B

Unordered_map B contain:
  KEY: x coord of the entity || VALUE: pointer to the AEntity instance
```

### Question 1:

First, are unordered_maps that fast for this kind of usage? I am very new to unordered_maps.

### Question 2:

Second, is this a viable way to add element?

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
   std::unordered_map <int, unordered_map <int, char*>> umap;

   (umap[4])[2] = "salut";
   std::cout << (umap[4])[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::unordered_map` is implemented in terms of a hash table, unlike a `std::map` which is implemented in terms of a tree. This means that for an `unordered_map`, access is in general O(1) where as for a `std::map` it is O(log n). There are a great many differences between these, I would suggest looking at a data structures book if you are unaware of the differences, but here are a few:

For `std::unordered_map`

- Allocates a single contiguous array of memory, you can use `reserve()` to prevent resizing at an inopportune moment, however because of the nature of hash tables, this will always allocate more space than you are actually ever going to use
- Calculating the hash is fast, but it could be faster to lookup a few pointers in a `std::map`

For `std::map`

- Dynamically allocates new memory for each element in your map, this can be slow if you are adding millions of elements to the map.
- Deleting elements is also a log n operation, which can be slow if you are doing this often.
- Because it is a tree, it is sorted, so you can traverse elements in order, something that is not possible with an unordered map

There are many others, I suggest looking them up, there are many duplicates of this type of question on stackoverflow already.

As for your seconds question, that is a valid way of adding and accessing an element in an unordered_map. However I would highly recommend using `reserve()` if you know the number of items you are going to be placing in the map.

Comment: The time complexities you describe aren't amortized bounds. While it depends on implementation details, we can assume some things for *most* implementations. Hash table access is *average* O(1) time, where "average" refers to "the average set of keys", not "the average time over a number of operations" (*that's* what amortized means, and it's orthogonal to best/average/worst case). There are some self-balancing with amortized worst-case O(log n) lookup, such as the Splay tree, but AFAIK `std::map` is virtually always a red-black tree, where lookup is O(log n) *worst case*.

Comment: Yes, I apologise, I was generalizing as it depends on the operation and I was talking about all of the operations, which isn't accurate. In general the operations for a hash table are O(1) and for a RB Tree are O(log n), some are worst case, some are amortized, some are average. I will remove the words amortized from my post

Comment: Well, I can't say I'm happy with that. It's better than wrong statements, yes, but these different terms exist for a reason. The information they carry is helpful in understanding both how the data structures work and in how they will perform in various cases. Plus, this misuse of notation makes the formalist in me sad ("O(log n) is a set of functions you notation monkeys, if you say something is in this set you gotta specify which quantity as a function of what in which case you consider dammit!").

Answer (score 2):

Others have already explained `unordered_map` vs. `map`, but if it is really speed you're after then I'd suggest using plain arrays (or vectors) instead. You say the number of entities can be "very large", by this I understand you're dealing with dense data (i.e. most of the coordinates contain an entity). An `unordered_map` is a kind of hashmap, meaning that dense data will fill up the buckets rapidly. Large buckets will reduce speed and increase memory usage, decreasing the advantages of using an `unordered_map`.

Reverting to arrays will always provide quicker access and insertion of entities, at the cost of some extra RAM. I don't know the range of possible coordinates, but let's say your map ranges from (0,0) - (1024, 1024). Using arrays of pointers for this would only use 1024 x 1024 x 8 bytes = 8MBytes of RAM no matter how much Entities you store in them. I'd have to run some tests to make sure, but I think that if your map is more than 80% filled with Entities, the array approach would actually use less RAM than the `unordered_map` approach.

To conclude I'd also like to mention that you shouldn't always focus on speed. Optimized C++ code is usually already very fast, and unless you really, really, really need the speed I'd suggest using the simpelest solution rather than the quickest.

Comment: With an identity hash function (exceedingly popular for integer keys), and the load factor being kept in check (should happen automatically), I actually expect the hash table to do extraordinarily well when faced with keys `[0, N]` with a few holes. The second paragraph is spot on though (+1). Also keep in mind that the hash table has little choice but to store additional data that's implicit or unnecessary in the arrays (at least the key, and possibly the hash). I expect the arrays to be competitive even at ~50% utilization.

Answer (score 0):

The `unordered_map` containers are faster than `map` containers when you need to access their key, but are considered to be less efficient when trying to access a subset of their elements. I think that if you were to access the pointers contained in the `unordered_map` containers directly that it would be less efficient.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/